# C++11 vector of vectors initialization

Tags: c++11, matrix, vector

In C++11, `{}` is preferred over `()` for variable initialization. However, I noticed that `{}` cannot correctly initialize the vector of vectors.

Given the following code, `vector<vector<int>> mat2(rows, vector<int>(cols, 2))` and `vector<vector<int>> mat4{rows, vector<int>(cols, 4)}` work as expected, but `vector<vector<int>> mat1{rows, vector<int>{cols, 1}}` and `vector<vector<int>> mat3(rows, vector<int>{cols, 3})` do not. Can anybody explain why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string parse_matrix(const vector<vector<int>>& mat)
{
    stringstream ss;
    for (const auto& row : mat) {
        for (const auto& num : row)
            ss << std::setw(3) << num;
        ss << endl;
    }
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    const int rows = 5;
    const int cols = 4;
    vector<vector<int>> mat1{rows, vector<int>{cols, 1}};
    vector<vector<int>> mat2(rows, vector<int>(cols, 2));
    vector<vector<int>> mat3(rows, vector<int>{cols, 3});
    vector<vector<int>> mat4{rows, vector<int>(cols, 4)};

    cout << "mat1:\n" << parse_matrix(mat1);
    cout << "mat2:\n" << parse_matrix(mat2);
    cout << "mat3:\n" << parse_matrix(mat3);
    cout << "mat4:\n" << parse_matrix(mat4);
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++14 -o vector_test2 vector_test2.cc 
$ ./vector_test2
mat1:
  4  1
  4  1
  4  1
  4  1
  4  1
mat2:
  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2
mat3:
  4  3
  4  3
  4  3
  4  3
  4  3
mat4:
  4  4  4  4
  4  4  4  4
  4  4  4  4
  4  4  4  4
  4  4  4  4
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a complete answer, but for every matrix you are using a different combination of parentheses and braces.  Recommend you standardise your calls before trying to debug.

Comment: @Immersive Had you actually read the question, you'd have realized that the variation of parens/braces is the whole point of inquiry.

Comment: Fair cop.  I skimmed a little and read it as "why isn't the output consistent".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a combination of reasons, uniform initialization is kind of broken for `std::vector<int>` (and more generally, vector of arithmetic type). Uniform initialization uses the same syntax as list-initialization (constructing from `initializer_list`); when the syntax is ambiguous, the constructor taking `initializer_list` takes precedence.

Thus, `std::vector<int> v(42);` means "use `std::vector(size_t)` constructor to create a vector of 42 zeros"; while `std::vector<int> v{42};` means "use `std::vector(std::initializer_list)` constructor to create a vector with a single element having value 42".

Similarly, `std::vector<int> v(5, 10);` uses two-parameter constructor to create a vector of 5 elements, all with value 10; while `std::vector<int> v{5, 10};` uses `initializer_list`-taking constructor and creates a vector of two elements, values 5 and 10.